# Sharepoint 2010 document templates

Tags: sharepoint

We have a requirement for a site wide document library that contains simple word letter templates.

From within a customer item on a list we need to be able to select one of these templates and then have the template populate with customer data such as name & address etc.

What’s the easiest way to achieve this? Ideally without using workflows.

Answer (score 1):

Then you shall assign a document template to a content type.

See this blog post, http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2011/01/07/using-content-types-with-document-templates-when-using-quotnew-documentrdquo.aspx

Comment: Hi,Yes, I can see how you do it with a content type, however its not clear how you prepopulate the properties in the document ?

Comment: That can be done either in SharePoint or in Word. In word the properties are visible under File > Info or inline in the "Document panel" as Server Properties. In SharePoint you can fill the properties in when creating, uploading or editing the document, whatever you fill in there will be shipped with the document and whatever you have in the document will be transferred to SharePoint.

Comment: The properties need to be filed from pre existing data though, whn you open the document based on a template in word, the user has to fill in the property values.

Comment: Do you have an example then, as I can only see examples where the user has to manually enter the data

Comment: Surely you have to use an event receiver in this instance to populate the fields ?

Answer (score 0):

Create fields in your template that display the document properties to "Autofill" them. This is done in the Insert tab of the ribbon, then by clicking QuickParts, then Document Properties.

The end result is that in addition to the File > Info or the properties bar, each property will also appear in the body of the document wherever you have inserted the field for it. These can then auto-update themselves based on the metadata stored with the document in the library (how often they update is a Word setting).

Comment: Hi, yes I get that, but how do you get the information into the properties via sharepoint from a list, rather than the user manualy entering them ?

Answer (score 0):

[Xpertdoc](http://www.Xpertdoc.com) Letter Management for SharePoint let's user pick a template from the context of a customer record, then generates a new document with customer data automatically merged inside the document.
CGU, an insurance company, estimate they save 0.5 million dollars per year by the efficiency gains introduced by Xpertdoc. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbqWiFt5dUA&feature=channel&list=UL.

Comment: Xpertdoc is a commercial product without a free / community version, correct ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use the [technique mentioned before](http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2011/01/07/using-content-types-with-document-templates-when-using-quotnew-documentrdquo.aspx) for the document creation based on content type.

As for auto-filling the property fields, I suggest you check out [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationlegacy/thread/5d0186ac-bea7-4488-baaf-97b307c290c6) that explains how to auto-fill properties when document is added.

You can also opt for a commercial solution such as [Harmon.ie for SharePoint](http://harmon.ie/) to retrieve your templates. They have a free version, if I'm not mistaken.